# NextJS Error: Element type is invalidServer Error Error: Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm working on a NextJS project right now (I'm a beginner) and got this error when I wanted to do npm run dev.
I've no errors in the code, nothing. No idea where it came from ...

Thank you in advance !

```js
Server Error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
ReactDOMServerRenderer.render
file:///home/selena/Documents/Devis/app-devis-lyon-js-react-sept21/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (4053:17)
ReactDOMServerRenderer.read
file:///home/selena/Documents/Devis/app-devis-lyon-js-react-sept21/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (3690:29)
Object.renderToString
file:///home/selena/Documents/Devis/app-devis-lyon-js-react-sept21/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (4298:27)
Object.renderPage
file:///home/selena/Documents/Devis/app-devis-lyon-js-react-sept21/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js (686:46)
Object.defaultGetInitialProps
file:///home/selena/Documents/Devis/app-devis-lyon-js-react-sept21/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js (316:51)
Function.getInitialProps
node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js (145:19)
Object.loadGetInitialProps
file:///home/selena/Documents/Devis/app-devis-lyon-js-react-sept21/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/utils.js (69:29)
renderDocument
file:///home/selena/Documents/Devis/app-devis-lyon-js-react-sept21/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js (699:48)
Object.renderToHTML
file:///home/selena/Documents/Devis/app-devis-lyon-js-react-sept21/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js (774:34)
runMicrotasks
<anonymous>
```

Comment: This is hard one to debug without seeing the full application. But the suggestion at the end of that error message ("You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.") is almost ALWAYS the correct issue in my experience.

Comment: @tknickman Thanks for the reply, it was indeed an import path error!